# Constructing a number different than x without revealing x

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

My question is not really about ZKP but is related to the socialist millionaire problem where A and B can check that their message x and y are different without revealing them. I would actually be interested in a method that allow B to construct a y different than x without A having to reveal any information about x. (x and y can be bounded by a small N)

Comment: The values $x$ and $y$ can be bounded by a small $N$, but do they have to? Otherwise, here is a straightforward statistically correct solution which involves no communication: Bob picks a uniformly random value $y$ over $\mathbb{Z}_k$, where $k$ is a very large number (say, $2^{128}$). Then no matter the value of $x$, it holds that $y$ is different from $x$ with overwhelming probability.

Comment: Yeah they have to be bounded by a small N that why it's a bit complicated.

Comment: Is A allowed to know the number?

Comment: No A must not have information over y and B no information over x. If not then A could just produce two number and give one to B. But A must not know y.

Comment: My point is I could use the socialist millionaire method iteratively until x and y are different which is doable quickly if N is not too small. But if there is a lot of participant like 5 or 10 and not just 2 then i dont think it is doable to just iterate the socialist millionaire method. In the end , x and y should just be like random number between 0 and N but they have to be diffrent.

Comment: So this is different. Your question ask for generating a random $y \neq x$, given an arbitrary $x$ known to A. But if it suffices for you that A and B simultaneously create a random pair $(x,y)$ such that $x \neq y$, where A knows $x$ and B knows $y$, then it is easier. Would that suffice?

Comment: Yes as long as A doesnt know y and B doest know x that would suffice